# How to grow the touchable area on React Native SVG elements on Android?

Tags: android, svg, react-native, react-native-svg

As part of a SVG sketch, I use a quite small dot as a slider control. To grow the touchable area I have added a thick, transparent border. This works on iOS, but not on Android. What can I do on Android to fix this? I've tried adding `hitSlop` and `padding`, but none of those seem to work on SVG elements.

Comment: Add a larger container around it and then center the SVG inside.

Comment: Thanks! That works, if I place the (transparent) larger container above the visible dot, rather than nesting them. Please add your solution as an answer and I'll mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add a transparent container around the Svg and handle your touches on that instead of on the Svg.

For example:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  <MySVGComponent />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: Hmmm, in my case the dot is part of a larger SVG drawing. But your suggestion did work for me if I just adapted it. I placed a larger, transparent, dot on top of the visible dot and made the transparent one draggable instead of the smaller one. I clarified my question a bit now.